# What's the intuition behind $T^*T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Let $T : V \to W$ be a linear transformation across inner product spaces over some field $\mathbb{F}$ and $T^* : W \to V$ be its adjoint. When considering $T$ composed with $T^*$, we have some unique properties:

1. If $T^*T = TT^*$, $V = W$, and $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$, then $V$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis with respect to $T$.
2. The eigenvalues of $T^*T$ are the singular values of $T$, which allows us to express $T$ as a diagonal matrix with respect to two orthonormal bases.

All of this seems pretty cool, but I don't really have any intuition for what $T^*T$ (or $TT^*$) means. Does anyone have an intuitive way of thinking about the transformation $T^*T$?

Comment: $T^{\ast} T$ is the map that occurs when you write $\langle Tv, Tv \rangle = \langle T^{\ast} T v, v \rangle$. So it tells you something about the quadratic form $\langle Tv, Tv \rangle$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem for more on this.

Comment: The comparison to be made is with $z = |z|{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta}$, see [polar decompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#:~:text=The%20polar%20decomposition%20of%20any,and%20a%20non%2Dnegative%20operator.&text=Lemma%20If%20A%2C%20B%20are,C%20such%20that%20A%20%3D%20CB.).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem see this

Answer (score 1):

This transformation is called the Gramian matrix. It serves a multitude of roles (such as SVD/PCA). It is a "sort of squaring" for matrices (that can be rectangular, unlike the normal squaring). The best analogy for this "sort of squaring" I know of is in the complex numbers. Where $T^2$ is like $z^2$, you can think of $T^* T$ to be like $z \bar{z} = |z|^2$. For complex-valued matrices of size $1*1$, these two notions are even precisely equivalent. Both the (conjugate) transpose and conjugation are involutions; and this corresponds to the product of a value with its involution.

Also note, if your product is non-commutative (or only defined one way around), then $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ might not be equal.

Comment: But it's also geometric. The $ij$-entry of $T^*T$ is the inner product of the $i$th and $j$th column vectors of $T$.

Comment: True I forgot to mention that. This is something that is very apparent when you understand covariance as an inner product (variance as a quadratic norm, standard deviation as a norm) and look at the covariance matrix/Gramian.